# How to whitelist directories for Units in systemd

Tags: security, systemd, namespace

There are many options available for Units (like services) in *systemd*. Three of them are called `ReadWriteDirectories`, `ReadOnlyDirectories` and `InaccessibleDirectories`. I'm using Debian 8.5 on a virtual machine. In some (newer?) versions of systemd they are called `ReadWritePaths`, `ReadOnlyPaths` and `InaccessiblePaths`. Can I use this options to whitelist directories, which should be accessible?

I have an application which is known to access some directories only. I would like to restrict the access to this directories. But it does not seem to have any effect if I use `ReadWritePaths` to specify this directories. The *manpage* says

> Directories listed in ReadWriteDirectories= are accessible from within the namespace with the same access rights as from outside.

But directories not specified in this option seems to be accessible the same way. How to deny access to everything not specified? Or is it up to my system that it doesn't work? Someone could thing that it may be possible to use `InaccessibleDirectories=/` to blacklist everything else but the manpage of a newer version, where the option is called `InaccessiblePaths`, says

> Entries listed in InaccessiblePaths= will be made inaccessible for processes inside the namespace, and may not countain any other mountpoints, including those specified by ReadWritePaths= or ReadOnlyPaths=.

Well, is there a possibility to use `ReadWriteDirectories` and `ReadOnlyDirectories` to setup a whitelist of directories? If it is not possible, why does `ReadWriteDirectories` exist sinde it seems to do nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to recent documentation ([link 1](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ReadWritePaths=), [link 2](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#TemporaryFileSystem=)), since 2018:

> Paths listed in `InaccessiblePaths=` will be made inaccessible for processes inside the namespace along with everything below them in the file system hierarchy. This may be more restrictive than desired, because it is not possible to nest `ReadWritePaths=`, `ReadOnlyPaths=`, `BindPaths=`, or `BindReadOnlyPaths=` inside it. For a more flexible option, see `TemporaryFileSystem=`.

> [`TemporaryFileSystem=`] is useful to hide files or directories not relevant to the processes invoked by the unit, while necessary files or directories can be still accessed by combining with `BindPaths=` or `BindReadOnlyPaths=`.

So the desired behaviour can be achieved:

```
[Service]
TemporaryFileSystem=/
BindPaths=/var/readwrite
BindReadOnlyPaths=/var/readonly
```

Comment: Very nice. I will accept your answer. I will properly not test this within the next few weeks but I think I can trust the documentation. Can you add a link to the documentation, through? For example https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#TemporaryFileSystem=

Comment: Good idea, thanks! I edited the answer to add links to those sections.

Answer (score 4):

`ReadWritePaths` and its ilk are only really useful when used alongside options that *blacklist* certain paths. If you know for a fact that your application should only be able to access certain paths, you can do some combination of the following:

- Set `ProtectSystem=strict`, and whitelist particular directories for writing with `ReadWritePaths`.
- Set `ReadOnlyPaths`, and whitelist particular directories with `ReadWritePaths`. If doing this with `/`, it does a superset of what `ProtectSystem` does (it also restricts /dev, /proc, and /sys, which you may not want). You can also use `PrivateDevices`, `ProtectKernelTunables`, and `ProtectControlGroups` to protect these directories.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ReadWritePaths=) was improved as well. However, there is one open question: Is there a possibility to whitelist read access? It does not seem so.

Answer (score 0):

Since you were specifically asking about **whitelisting read access**:

You might be able to achieve this with `InaccessiblePaths`, like so:

```
[Service]
...
InaccessiblePaths=/
ReadOnlyPaths=/etc/myapp.conf
```

See [systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already mentioned this setup in the question and quoted the documentation about it. According to this quote, it doesn't work. I also tested it before writing the question. However, I noticed that the documentation has changed a little bit since then. I don't know whether the behavior has changed in recent versions of Systemd. Have you tested it?

Comment: @JojOatXGME you're right. The [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ReadWritePaths=) say: _Paths listed in `InaccessiblePaths=` will be made inaccessible for processes inside the namespace along with everything below them in the file system hierarchy. This may be more restrictive than desired, because it is not possible to nest `ReadWritePaths=`, `ReadOnlyPaths=`, `BindPaths=`, or `BindReadOnlyPaths=` inside it. For a more flexible option, see `TemporaryFileSystem=`._